# Is the area of a parallelogram equal to the magnitude of the length of the diagonal?

Tags: geometry, cross-product

I understand that the area of a parallelogram is equal it the cross product of the two vectors that join to form it's two sides. But how about the diagonal of the parallelogram , is the cross product the same as the diagonal's magnitude?  Only reason I ask I am having trouble understanding torque.  The torque is said to be cross product but I can't see how applying force in the plane of a cross product can result in a force that is perpendicular.  Sorry for two part question but the first question really is a bit confusing unless one understands why I am asking it to being with and no matter which question I ask first they must eventually be put together to make sense.

Comment: Of course not. Just think of a square of side equal to $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: Force applied in the plane of a cross product does not result in a force that is perpendicular. It results in a torque vector that is perpendicular. A torque vector is not a force vector.

Comment: Moreover, a parallelogram has two diagonals, generically of different lengths. Which one are we talking about?

Comment: The one you use in a cross product.   A general formula for length of diagonal is all I am looking for but I messed up my question pretty bad.